# Wordpress to Salesforce WEB2lead integration

Tags: web2lead, website-integration

Hi,

I would like to implement the web2lead in wordpress site. Already I have the contact form so I would like to implement that existing contact form.

Where I can find the submit action and where I can I add the web2lead URL code.

Note: When I used the plugin(web2lead CRM), unable to see the url code and field id.

Please suggest.

Am new in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be easier than expected, webToLead provides you some precompiled html:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm

then in wordpress you can create a page, copy paste the HTML there and it's done. Users that will see that page will see the form which is already set-up to create leads upon submission. You can customize the css of that form the way you please.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to achieve the web2lead from wp, you need to have plugins.(I think you have already done that)
I am not sure you are using wp.com or wp.org. Based on the WP FAQ's, WP.com free plan you will not be able to achieve it (since they are not allowing to have plugins). There seems to be WP.com premium plan & WP.com enterprise/business plan. (I have not explored these two options).

You can check the following plugins which may give some idea

1. salesforce-wordpress-to-lead - http://wordpress.org/plugins/salesforce-wordpress-to-lead/
2. Gravity Forms - http://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-salesforce/installation/

Please let know which plugin you are currently using... which will provide me to elaborate on this answer.